# Projection with Entity Splitting in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, projection

I am using entity splitting to split properties across multiple tables - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617

This adds an inner join to the resulting SQL query.

I expected this join would only be included when the query projection includes the properties in the secondary table.  This is not the case when I use an anonymous type to isolate (project) a subset of needed fields.  The resulting SQL query only selects columns from the base table but still includes the join.

Is there anyway to continue to use entity splitting and only include the join when necessary?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, no. With Entity Framework, you can't lazy-load simple properties that are mapped to a column (which, in your case, would theoretically help you avoid the join); only navigation properties can be lazy-loaded. Perhaps you would need to employ table splitting instead to achieve the goal of eliminating the join.

For reference:
http://www.eidias.com/blog/2013/11/18/entity-framework-lazy-loading-properties

Comment: I believe a lazy-loaded navigation property results in a secondary query to fill the given property when accessed.  I'm talking about the initial query assuming the property is eager loaded.  I only want the join included if the projection includes a property from the joined table.